# using a filter to not show all images using simple HTML and Js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I have the following html (put html code which is relevant) and Jquery code (jquery code to long to input) which creates an isotype filter within my website on gallery images. Its working fine but when the page loads it shows all the images and i only want it to show the design images. I thought i would have to ammend the filter in the jquery code from 'all' to '.hdpe' but its not working. Any ideas thanks in advance

I've tried the suggested fixes on Stack Overflow but can't seem to fix my issue. I'm trying to get a "selected" category to keep from loading all the images on page load. I've tried to remove the "Show All" line but that does not help. I believe this to be a js problem.

HTML Code:- Html code i am selecting all images i donot want all images only particular selection HDPE Pipes images the load the images data.

```
<div align="center">
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="hdpe">HDPE Pipes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="sprinkle">Sprinkle Pipes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="spray">Spray Nozzle</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="irrigation">Irrigation Pipes</button>
</div>
```

Jquery:- This is Jquery code if i am adding ".hdpe" then also its taking all images i don't want to select all images please tell me what i have to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
        $(".filter-button").click(function(){
            var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            
            if(value == "all")
            {
                //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
                $('.filter').show('1000');
            }
            else
            {
    //            $('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
    //            $(".filter").not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').addClass('hidden');
                $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
                $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');
                
            }
        });
        
        if ($(".filter-button").removeClass("active")) {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

I amnot getting how to remove all images after loading my particular "hdpe" images please help in this scenario
I've tried the suggested fixes on Stack Overflow but can't seem to fix my issue. I'm trying to get a "selected" category to keep from loading all the images on page load. I've tried to remove the "Show All" line but that does not help. I believe this to be a js problem.

Comment: Can you and some examples for the image tags?

Comment: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/GzKKE .... check this link i don't want in that all images